# Is there any better algorithm to calculate the partition number p(n) than Euler's Pentagonal number theorem

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

Suppose I want to find partition number of n, aka p(n). Here [Euler's Pentagonal number theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675382/calculating-integer-partitions), a dynamic programming based solution is present, which has time and complexities O(n^2), O(n^2\log(n)) respectively.

Is there any improvement over this algorithm to reduce complexity or is there any proof showing that this algorithm is the best possible for this problem/ reducing complexity bellow this is NP-hard. Also what about the space-time trade off. Can we reduce time/space complexity by increasing space/time complexity respectively (keeping in mind that each complexity should not be more that O(n^3).

Comment: "For high values of n" - how high?

Comment: Google can usually save you the work of needing to create a question. E.g.: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675382/calculating-integer-partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2675382/calculating-integer-partitions). It also saves you from posting in the entirely wrong site.

Comment: @Paul Wrong site? Isn't that an algorithm?

Comment: @Breakingnotsobad the fact that a question is about an algorithm doesn't necessarily make it on-topic here. Considering that implementing an algorithm for this problem is fairly trivial, once the necessary mathematical basics have been dealt with, this question clearly belongs to mathematics.SE IMO.

Comment: @Paul I disagree. Programming certainly consists of two parts (if not more): figuring out the general algorithm and then implementing it. In a situation where an algorithm is based on a well known mathematical result, the translation of that result into these two steps is still not necessarily trivial. Consider that not everyone is well versed in maths, and of course there are different levels of experience in programming. SO should *especially* be a platform where people with such (and other) backgrounds can come to ask for help.

Comment: @Thomas may be a million

Answer (score 1):

The following recurrence can be directly translated to code:

[image: P(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n P(n,i)]

where

[image: P(n,k)=P(n-k,k) + P(n-1,k-1)],

[image: P(n,1)=1, P(n,n)=1, and P(n,k) = 0 for all k>n.]

```py
import numpy as np

def num_partitions(n):
    # recursive function with an auxiliary cache to avoid recomputing
    # the same value more than once
    def get(n, k, aux):
        # terminate the recursion
        if n < k:
            return 0
        if k == 1 or k == n:
            return 1

        # check if the value is already in the cache - if not, compute
        # it recursively
        if aux[n][k] == -1:
            aux[n][k] = get(n-k, k, aux) + get(n-1, k-1, aux)

        return aux[n][k]

    return np.sum([get(n, k, np.ones((n+1,n+1)) * -1) for k in range(1, n+1)], dtype=np.int)

import sys
print(num_partitions(int(sys.argv[1])))
```

Comment: Funny how your formulas look like in Dark Mode...

Comment: So you are suggesting a dynamic programming solution.

Comment: Correct, it follows directly from the recurrence equations given in the answer. Of course, how you implement this is up to you, the recursive version I propose has the advantage of being very simple to realize but alternatively, you could for instance do it with two nested for-loops in which you fill `aux` from small to large indices iteratively, i.e., without recursion.